# How can I use variables with nth-child selector?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

when I click on an arrow to the right, I want to hide the first one from a set of 20 tabs (by removing the class "w--tab-active" and show the second one (by adding the class "w--tab-active"). When I click again I want to hide the second one and show the third tab. Obviously I cannot use variables inside the nth-child selector, right? How else could I achieve that goal then?

This is how my code looks like:

```
var tabToHide = document.querySelector('.w-tab-content div:nth-child(1)');
tabToHide.classList.remove("w--tab-active");
var tabToShow = document.querySelector('.w-tab-content div:nth-child(2)');
tabToShow.classList.add("w--tab-active");
```

See the code under this url: https://der-gottwald-de.webflow.io/karussell-test

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve getting the list of elements which their class is .`w-tab-content`. Then you only need to take the first one or the second one, from the array. Herem instead of nth-child(1), you use [1].

```
   var tabToHide = document.querySelector('.w-tab-content')[0]; //this returns an array with the list of .w-tab-content, [0] will take the first one. 
    tabToHide.classList.remove("w--tab-active");
    
    
    var tabToShow = document.querySelector('.w-tab-content' )[1];//[1] will take the second one. 
    tabToShow.classList.add("w--tab-active");
```

Can you try this and let us know how it works?

Comment: sorry, that doesn't work. The problem is also that w-tab-content is the parent class. I wanted to select it's children. Anyway, I share the link where you can find the code and the example. When you click on the carousel, when the persons cycle through, I want to also cycle through the (hidden) tabs below it, containing the name and a short description of the person. https://der-gottwald-de.webflow.io/karussell-test

Comment: Can you inspect it from the url? (sorry I'm new here). If you need the full code I can post it but it could get quite long

Comment: I could but there is not any url

Comment: sorry I added the url. its https://der-gottwald-de.webflow.io/karussell-test